# How to replace a portion of string with a dot in regex?

Tags: php, regex

Here is the string that I want to replace:

```
<img src="./handler_image.php?i=c52bc1c30f560f4a15f99eeb8c04fea6" alt="Favicon" class="favicon">
```

I wrote this code:

```
$answer = preg_replace('/<img src="\./.*?>/', '', $answer);
```

but it does not work. If I replace it with:

```
$answer = preg_replace('/<img src=".*?>/', '', $answer);
```

It works but then it replaces all the images and not the ones whose `src` is in the format above. How should I modify this statement?

Comment: What (or where) is the expected portion of the string?!

Comment: @someOne Do you mean the part that will be replaced?

Comment: If that's what you want, then yes!

Comment: You need to escape the slash as well in the first one.

Comment: Note that you can easily target the tags you want with an xpath query: `//img[starts-with(@src, ".")]`

Answer (score 1):

The forward slash after the dot needs to be escaped too.

try this:

```
$answer = preg_replace('/<img src="\.\/.*?>/', '', $answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex working `<img src="\.\/.*?>`.

By the way, you can go there http://regexr.com/ to know how your regex is working.